# Max length of mysql unique name

Tags: mysql

Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key was too long; max key length is 1000 bytes (SQL: alter table `countries` add unique `countries_name_unique`(`name`))

how to solve this issue on cpanel

I change my.ini still not solved

Comment: please full result of show create table countries including engine collation and character set

Comment: From cpanel i can't found the solution